# Payslip in multiple currency in Odoo

Tags: currency, odoo

I want to generate two types of payslip in Odoo, one for employee who belongs to USA and one for employee who belongs to India. My Base / default currency is INR. Now I when I try to generate payslip for USA employees, I want USD currency in payslip, but I am getting payslip in INR. Please tell me how to handle this scenario

Please Note I have already set configuration for Multiple currency in settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of friend help me on this issue. To handle this situation, I have to create two company with two different currency and while creating employee I have set respective company. This way it will generate payslip in different currency. I hope this answer will help others.

Answer (score 1):

ّ know the question is a while ago but maybe can help.

You can set currency in account of **net salary rule**, by that your journal Entries will post in this currency but payslip stay working with company main currency

You will have two net salary rule and two salary structure for employees group, each one has rule with different currency